# What effect is this?

Tags: american-english

What is the effect called when the person cares about something or someone (they don't know why), but they're trying to convince themselves that they don't care/shouldn't care?

Example -

Alice just met this man. They talked for a bit, but he really didn't spark any feelings. She also doesn't know much about him. He gets severely hurt that night unexpectedly from an accident. She gets worried about him, and she's contacted by police since she's the last person he talked to. Now Alice is trying to convince herself not to care because she doesn't know the guy.

Comment: She is trying to remain ***aloof***

Comment: Disassociation effect

Answer (score 1):

to **detach from**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/detached) idiom

Now Alice is trying to **detach** herself **from** caring as she really did not know the guy.